# In-App Purchase Dynamic Subscription Price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm currently releasing our new app and it's using a subscription-based to avail the premium version of the app. But the price of the subscription will be based on how many products the user avail on that subscription. For example, the user subscribes for 5 products, so the recurring bill will be 5 x $10 (Price per product) = $50. Can this be obtained via IAP of Apple? I'm currently using Stripe as payment gateway to handle this but the app was rejected due to 
"3. 1.1 Business: Payments - In-App Purchase". Any suggestions will be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The prices of products in App Store Connect must be fixed, so you would need to create a unique product Id for every quantity of products that the user could subscribe to.